# Passing input value to action (ASP.Net MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have code in View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController")
{
    <input type="text" id="txt" />          
    <input type="image" src="/button_save.gif" alt="" />
}
```

How can I pass value of txt to my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string text)
{
 //TODO something with text and return value...
}
```

Comment: I believe that, if you want to get the automatic binding to work, the name of your controller parameter has to match the id of your input box, i.e. `string txt`

Comment: In any case, the best way to get controls to bind to some object you can use is to inherit the page from a `ViewData` object, and specify that `ViewData` object as your parameter to the controller method. See the NerdDinner tutorial for details. http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Give your input a name and make sure it matches the action's parameter.

```
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" />

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string txt)
```

Comment: Oh, yes! Sure! I forget to use name... And I forget that name of input must be same as name of parameter in my action. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Add an input button inside of your form so you can submit it

```
<input type=submit />
```

In your controller you have three basic ways of getting this data
1. Get it as a parameter with the same name of your control

```
public ActionResult Index(string text)
{

}

OR

public ActionResult Index(FormsCollection collection)
{
//name your inputs something other than text of course : )
 var value = collection["text"]
}

OR

public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
{
   var yourTextVar = model.FormValue; //assuming your textbox was inappropriately named FormValue
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified Microsoft MVC study "Movie" app by adding this code:

```
@*Index.cshtml*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSingleMovie", "Movies"))
{
    <br />
    <span>please input name of the movie for quick adding: </span>
    <input type="text" id="txt" name="Title" />   
    <input type="submit" />       
}

    //MoviesController.cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSingleMovie(string Title)
    {
        var movie = new Movie();
        movie.Title = Title;
        movie.ReleaseDate = DateTime.Today;
        movie.Genre = "unknown";
        movie.Price = 3;
        movie.Rating = "PG";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```